# How to get a window from a remote box, command line only?

Tags: remote-access, remote-x-session

I've got a remote Ubuntu box (a Linode) that I need to run a Java program which is not headless (it has a GUI window).  I am having the worst time trying to get this to work.  I don't need a whole desktop, just a window.  Starting with a minimally installed Ubuntu, can you recommend a lightweight strategy for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following to get it running on your VPS. Once you SSH in, do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install vnc4server openbox
vncserver # enter password, verify
vncserver -kill :1
```

- Now open up `~/.vnc/xstartup`, comment out the last line `x-window-manager &` and insert `openbox-session &` instead.
- Start VNC with `vncserver` -- ensure port 5901 incoming is open if you have a firewall enabled.
- Connect to display 1 (or port 5901) with any VNC client. You'll get the gray openbox-session background along with a default xterm and some VNC options:

  [image]
- Start your programs which need a GUI, etc. Right-clicking anywhere will let you open more terminals. You can change the default terminal to something other than xterm by installing another terminal emulator. I recommend `sakura` as it's lighter than installing `gnome-terminal`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this.  There's not a straightforward tutorial like this anywhere on the Internet. I had to `export DISPLAY=mybox:1` before running the Java program. For the VNC client I got "SSL/SSH VNC viewer" from the Ubuntu Software Center.  I could not get it to connect through SSH, but it worked when I changed authentication to "None" (sounds bad).

Comment: Is there a way to connect using certificates, like ssh, or are we limited to passwords?